# WSO2 API manager analytics quick guide setup not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed wso2 API manager along with analytics based on quick quide, but after statring server worker-api manger-dashborad and going to seee dashboard it just show blue screen and does not show any things.
packageing :
in wso2 folder there are two folders one is installed API manager and another folder is analytics folder.
Error in analytics-dashboard console :

```
Error in login to the uri 'analytics-dashboard'. Error: AM_SYSTEM_APPS does not exist in the AM_DB database.
```

Does my folder structre is correct?

[image]

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#quick-setup? Do you see any errors in the logs of either APIM or analytics?

Comment: You can check on the browser console .

Comment: I followed https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#quick-setup and somthing is not clear for me is that, does API manager and Analytics should be like the image that I have attached?because Analytics it slef has wso2am folder ..

Comment: Error in login to the uri 'analytics-dashboard'. Error: AM_SYSTEM_APPS does not exist in the AM_DB database.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found out that external wso2am that is installed, should be replace with wso2am that is in Analytics. In other words, wso2am and Analyitcs should be side by side.